# sbt console using ~; trying to see if REPL possible at cmd line; possible to w/o JRebel

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop, jrebel

Using SBT version 0.13.1 and Scala 2.10.4 on Ubuntu.
Trying to see if I can have a REPL at command line such as the Eclipse or IDEA REPL.

Is a way to run the console (REPL) using ~ such that changes in Scala files are reflected in the console session?

I know I can run ~ compile and ~ test, that reflect code changes and are recompiled.
And ~ console runs as well but does not seem to reflect changes.

I thought there may be a command like refresh - which refreshes SBT settings.

I have also tried running ~ compile in another session, but this does not update console.

I looked up docs on how to integrate JRebel in SBT and installed, set path, executed license, however still not being able to integrate from SBT.

Just wondering if I still need JRebel with latest SBT and Scala?